# When i try to install packages with pip i get an error

Tags: python, pip

Since I upgraded pip to version 20.0, I have had numerous problems related to installing/managing packages.
I have tried downgrading pip, but that also gives an error message.
Here is what I get when I try to install a package or downgrade pip;

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pip==19.0
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: c:\python39\Include\UNKNOWN
sysconfig: c:\python39\Include
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Collecting pip==19.0
  Using cached pip-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\kian-\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts\pip.exe
   from C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-jepxkgv7\pip.exe
  Moving to c:\users\kian-\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts\pip3.9.exe
   from C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-jepxkgv7\pip3.9.exe
  Moving to c:\users\kian-\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts\pip3.exe
   from C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-jepxkgv7\pip3.exe
  Moving to c:\users\kian-\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages\pip-21.1.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\~ip-21.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\kian-\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages\pip\
   from C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\~ip
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 393, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 77, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 782, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 810, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 720, in _install_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 418, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 462, in make
    return super().make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 407, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 307, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 242, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\kian-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 386, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1; however, version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried reinstalling python, adding variables to path, starting cmd on admin etc.
The issue seems to be that either some files are missing, or python can't detect/find them properly.

Comment: have you tried installation using python? `python -m pip --version` as pip had an issue for you, try through python.

Comment: @CoolCoder I have tried upgrading pip, but that gives the same error message as downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Because of my problems with python, I decided to reinstall windows.
Turns out I just forgot to add python to PATH.